# How to make Eclipse format according to template when typing

Tags: eclipse

I'm using eclipse Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0) on mac High Sierra.

I didn't like the default formatting. For example when I write a method, it puts a space before the brace like this `myMethod() {` instead of `myMethod(){` which I prefer.

So I changed the formatting template in `Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter`

Now when I do `CMD+shift+F` it formats it how I want without the whitespace.

However, it STILL adds the white space as I type in the method! I can't figure out how to stop it doing that. When I type `CMD+shift+F` it corrects it, so it knows what I want, but retains the old behaviour when I  type. Please save my sanity!

(Yes I've tried restarting eclipse!)

Thanks!

Comment: Is in _Preferences: Java > Editor > Typing_ in section _Automatically insert at correct position_ the checkbox _Braces_ checked? If yes, does unchecking it fix your issue?

Comment: @howlger Yes it does - thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ***Preferences: Java > Editor > Typing*** in section ***Automatically insert at correct position*** **uncheck** the checkbox ***Braces***.